# Preferences Not Saved in DialogPreference

Tags: android

My problem is the following: I have a component that extends DialogPreference. If I change the associated preference from outside the UI...

```
SharedPreferences.Editor ed= sharedPreferences.Edit();
ed.putInteger("Setting",aValue);
ed.commit();
```

...then, when I open the dialog the selected preference has not changed. Even if the shared preference value is modified, it still contains the previously set value.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: like this :

int value =sharedPref.getInt("settingKey", -1)

Comment: because you are saving under "Setting" and getting under "settingKey". Need to use the same key for saving and retrieving

Answer (score 0):

This has probably been solved long ago, but just in case....

Some ideas for things which might be causing the problem:

- The 'SharedPreferences' you are writing your value in might not be the same you are reading from.  You can test this by getting the value from the SharedPreferences and printing it (On Log or via a Toast) just after calling commit() on the dialog.  If you see the modified variable, you might actually be opening a new 'SharedPreferences' on the dialog, instead of the one you use on the calling activity, or
- You might be rewriting the default value again after your dialog.  For example, IF onResume() or other function is being called just after closing the dialog, and if the default value is written there.  I think this is unlikely, but might be something else to consider if you are sure that you are writing to the right 'SharedPreferences'.
- The function you are using when you write the variable might be wrong....  It is not clear to me how this would go undetected by the compiler or not fail otherwise, but as I see in the documentation for SharedPreferences.Editor, the function for writing an Integer value could be putInt(String key, int value) instead of putInteger(String key, int value).
- You might be reading or writing the wrong variable....  This might happen if you copy-pasted the putInt command and left the wrong key or the wrong value.  This is the kind of mistake that goes undetected for a long time, but it.... I guess it happens.  A mistake with similar effect would be having a typo on the key (Two different keys for reading and writing).

  Without the real code I think there is not much more I can suggest...  But I hope this can somehow be of help to anyone getting to this question.

  Regards.